# scalability of tornado websocket chat

Tags: python, tornado

In the tornado websocket chat example, participants are stored in the set ([link](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/demos/websocket/chatdemo.py#LC55))  , it is convenient in the case of a single server. But if run multiple instances of the application and nginx as a load balancer, how in this case, better to store the participants?

Comment: I'd say there's no difference if you run multiple instances. In the end every instance will have it's own set(). If you worry about the load balancer to switch users between instances, I don't think that'll work during a chat but I might be wrong. I you wan't all instances to use the same list of users you might consider a small db or a key-value store.

Comment: As I understand it, each instance will keep the connection only to their participants,different instances will be have a different list of users. But how the other instance will be notified of new messages in the chat? he

Comment: Since the `set` only belongs to one python instance and cannot be accessed by other instances, you have to create, like @pypat mentioned, a common, and FAST key-value store that can be accessed by all instances (like Memcached, Redis etc). One method is to use Redis Pub/Sub system to notify all instances of updated information. Hope my answer below helps a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may consider using the `pubsub` feature of Redis.
([link](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub))

Edit :

When your clients log on to your chatroom, they can `subscribe` to a channel, say `chatroom`. It does not matter which tornado instances they are using. 
Using [this module](https://github.com/leporo/tornado-redis) you can keep asynchronously listening to the channel.

If another client sends a message to your chatroom (that is publish a message to the channel `chatroom`), all tornado instances will automatically sends the messages to those who subscribed to the channel. Then you can send the message via websocket.

You can take a look at this [demo](https://github.com/leporo/tornado-redis/blob/master/demos/websockets/app.py) for the example.